# What is meaning of error: 'ev->QMouseEvent::pos' does not have class type

Tags: c++

I am programming in Qt and in between an event handler I wrote this:

```
void PaintedTextBrowser::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    ...
    QPoint *point = new QPoint(0, ev->pos.y());
    ...
}
```

And I get the error on compile:

> error: 'ev->QMouseEvent::pos' does not have class type

But when I modify the code as:

```
void PaintedTextBrowser::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    ...
    QPoint pos = ev->pos();
    QPoint *point = new QPoint(0, pos.y());
    ...
}
```

it works fine. What is the concept that I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, actualy - `QMouseEvent::pos` is not a class, [it's a function](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmouseevent.html#pos) returning a reference to `QPoint`, so you can't use dot operator on it.

I guess you wanted to write:

```
QPoint *point = new QPoint(0, ev->pos().y());
//                                   ^^
//                     note the parentheses
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are missing brackets:

```
void PaintedTextBrowser::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    ...
    QPoint *point = new QPoint(0, ev->pos().y());
    //                                   ^^
    ...
}
```